# How to extract specific value from HTML source with Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Python 3.8 and trying to extract a specific portion of an HTML source document.

The HTML contains two lines that start with a keyword, followed by a value in double quotes:

```
keyword: "http://www.somesite.com/sample.txt"
```

What I need to extract is just the value between quotes **if** it follows the first instance of the keyword, so the output should be `http://www.somesite.com/sample.txt`.

In my code so far, I am trying to do so with a regex match, but it is not matching anything:

```
import re

import bs4
import pyperclip
import requests


def get_value(url):

    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    regex = re.compile("file: \"(http[^\s\"]+\.txt)\"")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    return regex.search(soup.text).group().replace('file: "', '').replace('"', '')

# Print the URL from the clipboard
print(pyperclip.paste())

# Call get_value to return the required value between double quotes after file:
my_value = get_value(pyperclip.paste())

# Copy the final value to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy(my_value)
```

I get the following Python error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` when executing that.

I am not very familiar with regex but also believe there is a better way to extract this data as Stack Overflow's own RegEx Wiki suggests **not** using regex on HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are getting is most likely due to no matches being found in `regex.search`, in which case it returns `None`, and calling `.group` method on `None` returns the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Without having the specific HTML sample you're working with it's hard to say why it doesn't match. Based on the example in the post, it could be because your regex pattern is looking for strings starting with `file` and HTML contains lines starting with `keyword`.

If there is a match in HTML, it should work. Here's an example:

```
import bs4
import re

html = """
<html>
    <body>
        <p>file: "http://www.somesite.com/sample1.txt"</p>
        <p>file: "http://www.somesite.com/sample2.txt"</p>
        <p>file: "http://www.somesite.com/non-matching.jpg"</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

regex = re.compile("file: \"(http[^\s\"]+\.txt)\"")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
regex.search(soup.text).group(1)
```

Output:

```
'http://www.somesite.com/sample1.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer; it is close, I think. However, I am only interested in getting the **first** match found (instead of `findall()`) and the file extension should not matter.

Comment: Right, so if you only need the first match, then you can use `.search` like you did in the original post, and then `.group(1)` to return the value in parentheses (I've updated my answer to do that)

Comment: Didn't quite get your point on *the file extension should not matter*. If you want to match any extension, then your regex pattern should be different, i.e. without the `.txt` part: `file: \"(http[^\s\"]+)\"`

Comment: Looks great and does exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the part of string shared by you. Try using the below regex

```
regex = re.compile(r'file:.*\"(.*)\"')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
return regex.match(soup.text).group(1)
```